# Java: How to explicitly redirect System.err to the console (i.e. restore the default behavior)?

Tags: java, max-msp-jitter

I'm writing a plugin for a closed source application called [Max/MSP](http://cycling74.com/products/max/). To work with Max/MSP, my code needs to extend a class provided by the vendor (com.cycling74.max.MaxObject).  This class overrides `System.err`, so that calls to `System.err.println` direct messages to a special error log provided by the application.

This behaviour is fine in deployment, but it's problematic during testing. I'm presently trying to write a test suite that runs my code outside of the host application.  When I do this, calls to `System.err` raise exceptions because the application's error log isn't available.

Does anyone know how I can "undo" Max/MSP's error redirection, so that, during testing, calls to `System.err.println` show up in the java console?

EDIT

I tried @MadProgrammer's suggestion of cacheing a reference to the error PrintStream before creating my Max object.

```
import com.cycling74.max.*;

public class MyMaxObject extends MaxObject{

    public MyMaxObject(){}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PrintStream oldError = System.err;
        MyMaxObject o = new MyMaxObject();
        System.setErr(oldError);
}
```

I can't get this to work. When I run this code in a debugger, I find that `System.err` has type `com.cycling74.io.ErrorStream` at the first line of my main method. So it seems that the redirection has already happened by then. If this is the case, how can I get a reference to the error stream before it's redirected?  (Where on earth would I put that code, if not at the top of `Main`?)

EDIT 2

Ok, figured it out.  I just needed to move my test code (e.g. the `Main` method above) into a separate class. Once I did this @MadProgrammer's solution worked perfectly.

Comment: You could mock System.err.println in your tests with a mocking framework (jmockit can do that, others probably can too).

Comment: @dB' it's because you can't be touching Max/MSP classes before you access `System.err`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need a reference to `System.err` BEFORE it's redirected.

```
PrintStream oldError = System.err;
```

Once you've initialized `MaxObject` (or what ever part of the system overrides the `System.err` you need to reassign the reference...

```
System.setErr(oldError);
```

Comment: Thanks for this... but I can't quite get your solution to work. I've edited my question with more info. Any ideas on next steps?